# SwiftUI how to refresh one single tabview without switching tabbar

Tags: swiftui

I need do some refresh on some view after networking request completion, but my tab bar auto switched to first tabview after refreshing the page, here is my code:

```
//tab view
struct PricesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var netWorkManager = NetworkManager.shareInstance
    var body: some View {
        if netWorkManager.dataList.isEmpty {
            LoadingView().onAppear(perform: netWorkManager.fetchPricesData)
        } else {
            Text("Prices").foregroundColor(.red)
        }
    }
}

...

//main view
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("home")
            }
            AlertsView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "flag.fill")
                Text("alerts")
            }
            LinksView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "link.icloud")
                Text("link")
            }
            PricesView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bitcoinsign.circle")
                Text("prices")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use selection and tag.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selection = 0 // <- Here declare selection
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) { // <- Use selection here
            HomeView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("home")
            }.tag(0) // <- Add tag
            
            AlertsView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "flag.fill")
                Text("alerts")
            }.tag(1) // <- Add tag
            
            LinksView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "link.icloud")
                Text("link")
            }.tag(2) // <- Add tag
            
            PricesView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bitcoinsign.circle")
                Text("prices")
            }.tag(3) // <- Add tag
        }
    }
}
```